# How to unit test aws athena sql queries in python lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, moto

I have a python lambda that will call an SQL query to Athena for pulling certain data for my lambda calculation. How do I unit test Athena queries in the lambda? As lambda uses some other services I used MOTO to mock services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write an unit test code locally as long as the business logic is separated from lambda specific code like even and context. [Here](https://davidallenfox.wordpress.com/2017/06/15/getting-started-with-serverless-framework-and-python-part-2/) is an example.

Unfortunately, moto has not supported Athena yet. You can make an issue to request a new feature with your use cases or you can make new pull request. Anyway the community would help you.
[GitHub - moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto)